# convert a 2-D table into a tree structure

Tags: vba

I'm trying to extend the BOM tree using VBA, but I've been heading into it for several days, there is nothing I can get.

I have a table like this:

```
Parent  Component
A   A1
A   A2
A   A3
A   A4
A   A5
A1  A6
A1  A7
A1  A8
A1  A9
```

And I want to output the table using VBA like this:
1)

```
Level   Part
0   A
.1  A1
..2 A6
..2 A7
..2 A8
..2 A9
.1  A2
.1  A3
.1  A4
.1  A5
```

or 2)

```
Level_0 Level_1 Level_2
A       
    A1  
        A6
        A7
        A8
        A9
    A2  
    A3  
    A4  
    A5
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show what exactly you have tried so far?

Comment: I write a recursive function to generate the tree, but it doesn't work.

Comment: ok, just post it so we can elaborate on that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
Public i As Long
Public myLevel(1000) As Long
Public myPart(1000) As Long



Sub test()

i = 1

Debug.Print 0 & Chr(9) & "A"
Extend_BOM_Structure ("A")



End Sub

Sub Extend_BOM_Structure(Part As String)



    Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection, rs As New ADODB.Recordset, _
                                    rs2 As New ADODB.Recordset

    Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection

    Dim mySQL As String

    mySQL = "SELECT Component FROM Table1 WHERE Parent = " & Chr(34) & Part & Chr(34)

    rs.Open mySQL, cn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockBatchOptimistic

    With rs

        Do While Not .EOF

        Debug.Print 1 & Chr(9) & .Fields(0)

        Call Extend_BOM_Structure(.Fields(0))

        .MoveNext

        Loop

    End With

    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

But I have no idea on how to generate the level number.

The below is Immediate Window output:

```
0   A
1   A1
1   A6
1   A7
1   A8
1   A9
1   A2
1   A3
1   A4
1   A5
```